# Dell laptop 'dies' after disconnecting from the external monitor

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, power-management, shutdown

I run Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 93 generic on Dell laptop. When I disconnect the notebook from the large external screen (Benq BL 2405), DVI connection and close the lid, next I time I open the lid the laptop is dead, i.e. it's on and consuming energy but I the screen is black and I could't get it work. So the notebook keeps 'working' after closing the lid and saps the energy until the battery dies, but I can't do anything to actually get it to work. This only started after istalling Ubuntu 16.04 and disconnecting from the large screen.

Comment: My daughter has a Dell Inspiron 14 and it has the same problem (consuming battery energy even turned off). And it has Windows 10... I think it's hardware issue. Otherwise you can investigate at `/var/log/syslog`and `dmesg` in time gap between suspending and "forced" awake to see any error message.

Comment: What happens when you use alt+ctrl+F1? Do you get a termninal? This might be happening because your Xscreen monitor is being disabled while running init 5 (The GUI .. ctrl+alt+F7).

Comment: What does  the lid switch setting have? '/etc/systemd/logind.conf"  HandleLidSwitch="??" Is it pounded out?

Comment: HandleLidSwitch=suspend    
  HandleLidSwitchDocked=hibernate
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3369/what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-and-suspend

Comment: You also have two questions, one is how do wake from suspend <use space bar>? Second why is it suspending<lid switch setting> . http://guruquest.net/question/how-to-keep-ubuntu-run-and-display-when-laptop-lid-is-close/?utm_source=GooglePlus&utm_medium=urlshare&utm_campaign=stackoverflow

Comment: @shadowbq: no, I have 1 question. No, your link doesn't work.

Comment: @shadowbq: you obviously didn't read my question, as I clearly stated this started after I've installed 16.04. This is certainly a bug, but I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 0):

When you close the lid, your notebook by default hibernates or goes to suspend-to-ram. As long as anexternal Monitor is attached (and can be detected), it stays awake, because you might sit in front of it and using it. When you detatch the monitor, it goes "asleep", because nobody obviously can be using it (except, of course, remotely via network). So it does, what most people would expect it to do.

When you reopen the lid, just press the POWER botton like switching it on, and it will be there like it never slept.

You can configure it to behave differently (System --> Power) if you prefer.

TomTomTom

Edit: Not a joke at all. I've seen several notebooks on 16.04 behaving as I described. But in your comment above you hinted the solution yourself:

```
    HandleLidSwitch=suspend HandleLidSwitchDocked=hibernate #LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
```

There are the configurations "suspend" and "hibernate" you experience, first one if your are on battery, second one if power is attached. You might want to change them to `ignore`, so nothing sould change when you close the lid.

Comment: Is this a joke? Yes, of course I've tried this many times, and I've tried changing the power settings you mention. It just doesn't work. It's certainly a bug, because it only started when I installed 16.04, but I can't find which.