# What does "Interactive" do in Power settings

Tags: gnome, suspend, power-management, gnome-power-manager

I got the answer for all, but Interactive from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3369/what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-and-suspend).
But what does Interactive do?

[image]

(anyone from Windows, suspend = sleep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "*Interactive*" option should show a prompt with multiple power button press options.
In other words after pressing the power button a pop-up dialogue should appear containing separate buttons for Shutdown/Logout/Suspend/Hibernate allowing the user to select any one of them and then the computer will perform the chosen action.

But the catch is the "Interactive" option doesn't work as expected in newer versions of GNOME shell (most probably v3.18 and later). So most probably your computer would just suspend after power-button-press without showing any prompt.

Not sure whether it's an intended feature or a bug, this [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=755953) is marked as "resolved fixed" without actually fixing the issue.

Comment: yeah it sleeps, I have no problem with it. Funny it is an option on lid close, if you close the lid, how would you choose?

Comment: @KristoferVesi Probably just bad design implementation from GNOME and/or Tweak Tool developers.