# Hibernate vs Poweroff

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, systemd, hibernate

I have seen this question before [What is the difference between Hibernate and Suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3369/what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-and-suspend) , but I still have some lingering questions about suspending, and hibernating and all the such.

Is there a difference (aside from the naming scheme) between `systemctl poweroff` and `systemctl hibernate`? as hibernate seems to actually power off the system after saving the machine state to disk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am aware, hibernate creates a complete 'image' of the system state that is restored on restart. Poweroff, on the other hand, shuts down the system which includes clearing tmp files and memory caches.

Comment: As far as performance in wake up, is there a difference? (A noticeable one)

Comment: YMMV - it depends on many factors such as HDD or SSD, speed of processor, how many autostart programs you have set. Only way to be sure for your system is to try both methods and see if you notice a difference.

Comment: More or less what I expected, honestly the difference is negligible at this point :shrug: